# VM from Google Cloud SQL rejecting connection

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-compute-engine

I have set up a google cloud sql server using the tutorial on youtube. However, Whenever I try to connect to it through the browser, the connect to it through the browser, the error i am getting is `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` . The firewalls I have set up correlate to whats in the browser. I can also SSH into the VM. But the VM always rejects my connection. I have been trying for days.

[image: Here are my VM settings allowing http connections]

[image: Here is my VM External IP Address]

[image: This is what the browser tells me]

Here are my VM Settings allowing http connections

Here is my VM External IP Address
Here is what the browser tells me when i attempt to connect.

Comment: did you put your machine Subnet in the Authorized Networks, under access control in Cloud SQL?

Comment: @George I did. I put my public IP address under my access control in cloud SQL. I also put my VM IP address under access control also.

Comment: in your "default" firewall, do you have a rule allowing http on port 80? try turning off the iptables on the machine also just to test.

Comment: @George yes I do and ok I will try that

Comment: @George I have tried turning off the ip tables but to no avail. I believr the problem is I have the wrong ip address listed. When I google my ip address it gives me an address that does no connect to my machine. However I can connect using the ip address when I ipconfig in the terminal. But google wont allow me to add that ip address in the Access Control. Only the one they give me when I search for my public ip address.

Comment: Is your SQL instance in the same region as the other instance?

Comment: @George the Cloud SQL instance is in the United States region. The VM instance is in the us-central-1f region

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58441/discussion-between-george-and-superuserdo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kQXgjIfLgo?

In that video there are some steps missing such as install the web server (e.g. Apache) and PHP in the VM. After you install them, you can execute the following command in the VM:

```
php /var/www/index.php
```

If it works you can see the source code of the resulting page and if not you'll have an error to solve (maybe a package to install like php-mysql).

Once you can see the resulting page in the VM you can try to load the page through the browser of your machine. If it still doesn't work there is an Apache or network misconfiguration.

Comment: I am on mac and when I do the equivalent to what your saying, the results are correct. Everything is fine when im connecting locally but when trying to use google cloud sql it  gives me the error. My apache listens to port 80. If there is a problem with ny apache configuration could you tell me where it may be located?

Comment: I was going to tell you to install Apache in the VM instead of in your Mac but I have read the chat and I'm glad to hear the issue was solved after you did it.